# I want to read .dat files in separate columns, then save it as .csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I used pandas to read the .dat file from local storage

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('ratings.dat', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Then save it to local storage

```
dataDf = df.to_csv('ratings.csv')
```

[This is the result of the code. I need the columns separate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFOkb.png)

Comment: what happens if you try `pd.read_csv('ratings.dat', sep=':')` in anycase, welcome to SO, have a read of [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Shuqran. It worked. Now I can do the rest of the task myself. Thanks

Comment: No problemo, I would delete this question and have a read of the community guidance, you'll get _much_ better help if you ask a proper question :) good luck habibi